# General proof of irrational roots.

Tags: real-analysis

We can assert that $\sqrt n$ is irrational for every number $n$ that is not a perfect square. Let $n$ be such a number. ***Then there exists a prime number $p$ which divides $n$ an odd number of times.***

I can't quite grasp why this is true.

Comment: Suppose to the contrary that every $p$ that divides $n$ does so an even number of times, say $n = p_1^{2k_1}p_2^{2k_2}\cdots p_r^{2k_r}$. Then $\sqrt{n} = p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$, that is, $n$ is a perfect square.

Comment: I was about to delete this post, realised how silly i was. Thanks for the quick reply David.

Comment: Just make sure you take care of the trivial case $n=1$ seperately :)

Comment: The trivial case is no different from the others: 1 is a perfect square, and every prime divides 1 an even number of times; no prime divides 1 an odd number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By contradiction: if all prime factors of $n$ have an even exponent, then $n$ is a perfect square.